# Ubuntu 18.10 RC install - where is disk encryption

Tags: server, system-installation, 18.10

I'm going through the 18.10 installer and while I'm liking the new streamlined setup where is the disk encryption step? I see `entire disk` and `entire disk w/ LVM`, I went w/ LVM and there's the fdisk review but no additional options to add a disk encryption before booting the OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new "Live-Server" image doesn't have any disk-encryption options yet. But the alternative iso which uses the old/but-finished stable installer, does have disk-encryption options.

[Direct Download](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/daily/current/cosmic-server-amd64.iso)

[Directory Browsing](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/daily/current/)

Update: For 19.04

[Direct Download](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/19.04/release/ubuntu-19.04-server-amd64.iso)

[Directory Browsing](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/19.04/release/)

Comment: for 18.10 LTS http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.2/release/